# how to add new value to json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

```
pin = [
    {
        "id": 26,
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "user",
                "description": "example",
                "pin": 26,
                "commenter": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "admin",
                "description": "example",
                "pin": 26,
                "commenter": 17
            }
        ],  
    }
]
```

user would post a new comment and I would want it to add the new comment under the comments array
I tried putting it this way but the other values turned out blank

```
   case ADD_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        pin: [...state.pin.commentstory, action.payload]
      };
```

how would you add a new value to the comments array?

Comment: i think you want `pin: [...state.pin, action.payment]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the `action.payload` to your `pin` array:

```js
case ADD_COMMENT:
  return {
     ...state,
     pin: [...state.pin, action.payload]
  }
```

To add an item to the `comments` array in the `pin` array, you need a way to identify *which* item in the `pin` array should receive the update.

```js
case ADD_COMMENT:
  // suggested payload structure
  const pinId = action.payload.pinId;
  const newComment = action.payload.comment;

  const newPins = state.pin.map(p => { 
     if (p.id !== pinId) { return p };
     return {...p, comments: [...p.comments, newComment]};
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    pin: newPins
  };
```